# Solving $ \left(\frac{ ( x^{3}+1 )^{3}+8 }{16}\right) ^{3}+1=2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, substitution, cubics

> Solving :
>   $$\left(\frac{  ( x^{3}+1 )^{3}+8 }{16}\right) ^{3}+1=2x$$

My Try :
$$\left(\frac{  ( x^{3}+1 )^{3}+8 }{16}\right) ^{3}=\left(\dfrac{(x+1)^3+2^3}{2^4}\right)^3$$

$$ x^3+a^3=(x+a)^3-3ax(x+a)$$

$$\left(\frac{ (x^3+3)^3-6(x^3+1)(x^3+3)}{16}\right) ^{3}=\left(\dfrac{(x^3+3)(1-6(x^3+1))}{2^4}\right)+1=2x$$

Now what ?

Comment: The sum of 2 cubes can be factorised by $a^3 + b^3 = (a + b)(a^2 - ab + b^2)$. This might help you since there are at least 3 sum of 2 cubes there.

Comment: By inspection $x = 1$ is a solution, and consulting a CAS shows that $(\textrm{l.h.s.}) - (\textrm{r.h.s.}) = (x - 1) (x^2 + x - 1) p(x)$ for some irreducible polynomial $p$ of degree $24$ with no real roots.

Comment: Perhaps there is some slick trick to solve this, but as it appears this seems to be a horrible, almost criminal, equation to solve.

Answer (score 6):

Let $\frac{x^3+1}{2}=y$ and $\sqrt[3]{2x-1}=z.$

Thus, from the given we obtain $\frac{y^3+1}{2}=z.$

Now, let $x>y$.

Thus, $$x>y=\frac{x^3+1}{2}>\frac{y^3+1}{2}=z,$$ which says that
$$x>y>z.$$
But from $y^3+1=2z$ and $z^3+1=2x$ we obtain
$$0=y^3-z^3+2(x-z)>0,$$ which is a contradiction.

By the same way we'll get a contradiction for $x<y$.

Id est $x=y$, $$x^3-2x+1=0$$ or
$$x^3-x^2+x^2-x-x+1=0$$ or
$$(x-1)(x^2+x-1)=0,$$
which gives the answer:
$$\left\{1,\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2},\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}\right\}$$

Comment: Slight variant:
define $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto\frac{x^3+1}{2}$.
$f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$, so if $x \lessgtr f(x)$,
then $f(x) \lessgtr f(f(x))$, therefore
$f(f(x)) \lessgtr f(f(f(x)))$, therefore $x \lessgtr f(f(f(x)))$.
Hence, $x = f(f(f(x)))$ iff $x = f(x)$.

Comment: @Calum Gilhooley I saw this way. I just wrote this idea differently.

Comment: It was merely my take on what you had written, only a "slight" variant, as I said. Yours is a nice answer; I just wanted to make it a little easier to see at a glance.